# Localization of module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, localization

Let denote localization of $M$ at $S$ as the $S^{-1}R$-module $S^{-1}M$

Question is as follows:

> Let $R$ be an integral domain and $M$ is an $R$-module. Show that 
>   $M=0$ iff $S^{-1}M=0$ for all $S=R-p$ where $p$ is a prime ideal.

I think it is obvious question. I try to prve. But I am not sure that I understand what the question ask. For example I don't use $p$ is prime ideal

My proof is as follows. Is it true?

=>

$m/s \in S^{-1}M$ but $m=0$ then $m/s=0$ that is $S^{-1}M=0$

<=
Let $S^{-1}M=0$ choose an element m/s and say $m\neq0$ because S is in R then $s\in R$ multiply m/s by s then $m=0$ 
Note that $0\notin S$

Comment: In <=n, you didn't prove that $m=0$ (in $M$), but that $\dfrac m1=0$. (in $S^{-1}M$).

Comment: Is not same? What is meaning of m/1?

Comment: It's he element of $S^{-1}M$ with denomimator $1$. All elements of $S^{-1}M$ can be written as $\dfrac ms$, with $m\in M$ and $s\in S$. It's just like fractions in $S^{-1}A$, except the numerator is in $M$, and the condition for geing $0$ is a little more complex$\dfrac ms=0\iff \exists t\in S$ such that $tm=0$ in $M$. This is because the module $M$ can have torsion. Note it is the same condition for  the ring of fractions if $R$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: But R is integral domain. This means if $sx=0$  then $x=0$

Comment: Not if  $x\in M$ \  unless the module is *torsion-free*. Counter-example: $\mathbf Z5\mathbf Z$ is a $\mathbf Z$-module, but for all $x$ in this module, $5x=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is correct, the second is not. Do you know when $x/1 = 0$ in $S^{-1}M$?

**Hint:** Try to choose a non-zero element $x$ of $M$ and observe that the annihilator $\text{Ann}(x)$ of $x$ is contained in some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Then let $S = R - \mathfrak{m}$. What can you tell about $x/1$ in $S^{-1}M$?

---

First let us recall that an $R$-module is just an abelian group $M$ equipped with a scalar product by elements of $R$ which acts linearly on $M$; a bit like a vector space where the base field is not a ring.
For example, you can see that the $\Bbb{Z}$-modules are precisely the abelian groups.

Now, consider an $R$-module $M$ and a multiplicatively closed subset $S$ of $R$. Then by definition of localisation we know that $x/s = y/r$ in $S^{-1}M$ if and only if there is some $t \in S$ such that
$$
(rx - sy)t = 0
$$
in $M$. In particular, this means that $x/s = 0$ in $S^{-1}M$ if and only if there is an $r \in S$ such that $rx = 0$.

For what we said above this is perfectly fine even if $R$ is a domain, because $M$ doesn't need to be a subset of $R$. For example, every quotient ring of $R$ has a natural structure of $R$-module.

The *annihilator* of an element $x \in M$ is defined as
$$
\text{Ann}(x) := \{r \in R : rx = 0\}
$$
and you can check that this is an ideal of $R$. As such, it must be contained in some non-trivial maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

So, suppose that for every prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ we have $M_{\mathfrak{p}} := S^{-1}M = 0$ with $S = R - \mathfrak{p}$. If $M \neq 0$ then we can find a non-zero $x \in M$. Since every maximal ideal is also prime we have $M_{\mathfrak{m}} = 0$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is the maximal ideal containing $\text{Ann}(x)$. In particular, for every $s \in R - \mathfrak{m} \neq \varnothing$ we have $x/s = 0$, which by what we said above means that $rx = 0$ for some $r \in S$. But this is absurd, because $\text{Ann}(x) \cap S = \varnothing$, hence $x$ must be $0$. Since $x$ was arbitrary it follows that $M = 0$.

On the other hand, $M = 0$ immediately implies $S^{-1}M = 0$ for every multiplicatively closed subset $S$ of $R$.

**Note** that this proof shows that the hypothesis that $R$ is a domain actually isn't necessary. All you need is that $R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

Comment: $x/1=0$ means x=0 am I right? @A.P

Comment: Not always; that's the problem with your proof. $x/1 = 0$ implies that there is an $s \in S$ such that $sx = 0$ in $R$.

Comment: Can we say that $s^{-1}\in S$ because S is multiplicatively closed?

Comment: But R is integral domain. This means if $sx=0$ Then $x=0$

Comment: I'm sorry, I shouldn't have said "in $R$" but "in $M$". For example, the group $\Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$ can be seen as a module over $\Bbb{Z}$, and $5 \cdot x = 0$ for every $x \in \Bbb{Z}/5\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Also, you can't say that $s^{-1} \in S$ if $s \in S$. The inverse of $s$ might not even *exist* in $R \supset S$.

Comment: @A.P. maybe its better to edit the answer based on comments.+1

Comment: @user1 Done. Is this clear enough, corcia candy?